# Scheduled Copy Bigquery View/Query to Google Sheet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, node.js, javascript

I have a BigQuery View/Query that every morning I need to run and copy the result to a Google Sheet.
I am using Javascript, and plan to use the node.js [BigQuery client library](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/) and the [Google Sheets node.js API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) for interacting with BigQuery and Google Sheets.
I would like to achieve this using Google's Cloud Functions but I'm not sure how to put it all together and how to schedule it.

Can someone explain which tools/products I should use and how to string them together.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your scenario should involve using Cloud Functions to host the code you want to execute and Cloud Pub/Sub and Cloud Scheduler in order to trigger it as explained in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub).

To sum up the article, you should:

- Develop the code that queries the BigQuery View and dumps the result to Google Sheet.
- Make a Cloud Function that triggers using Cloud Pub/Sub with the code you developed earlier. Create a new Pub/Sub topic for this task.
- Create a Cloud Scheduler job with the frequency you need that targets the Pub/sub topic you created before. Take a look at [this page](https://crontab.guru/) if you want to nail the unix-cron format.

These should be all the steps.